# Linearization of $\sum_k (y_{k}^2+x_k\,y_k)$

Tags: linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, linearization

How can I linearize $\sum_{k} (y_{k}^2+x_k\,y_k)$? when $y$ is a variable and $y\ge0$, and $x$ is a binary variable.

Comment: Does $y_k$ have an upper bound?

Comment: @RobPratt Since $y_k$ is the price of the commodity $k$ in my model, we can consider a fixed upper bound for all commodities. $y_k\le h$

Answer (score 0):

You can linearize the $x_k y_k$ exactly:
https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/39/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-a-binary-and-a-non-negative-continuous-variable?r=SearchResults

But for the linearization of $y_k^2$ you’ll have to settle for an approximation:
https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/180/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-two-continuous-variables?r=SearchResults